# the ratio of conductivity/conductivities of two phases

Tags: grammar

When I search the following expressions in Google Scholar I find:

1- "the ratio of conductivities of two phases" --> **3 results**

2- "the ratio of conductivity of two phases" --> **30 results**

which indicates that the second expression is grammatically correct. However, I think the correct one should be the first expression which uses the plural form after the term "the ratio of".

Where is my mistake? Is the word "conductivity" in the second expression used as an adjective? Then, is the first expression wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "the ratio of *the* conductivities of *the* two phases" -- 38 results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, can 33 results be considered a statistically significant sample? The conferring of 'grammaticality' on a usage (and I agree that this example is really about grammar rather than semantics) needs to be based on a much larger sample set.

Secondly, there is often a nod towards non-countness when dealing with a situation where plurality is obviously involved, but actual physical counting seems far from one's thoughts – for example in the sentence below, with 'mood' [[WAMU.org](https://wamu.org/story/19/05/15/is-the-u-s-itching-for-a-fight-with-iran/)]:

> The New Yorker’s Robin Wright analyzed the mood in both
>   countries.

And sometimes where maths is not far from the surface, but still just below [[JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.5951/mathteacmiddscho.19.6.0386?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)]:

> Why is it important to estimate the height of such trees?

But thirdly, this should not be pushed to silly extremes, and I'm with you that 'ratio' in your example brings counting / manipulating figures very much into the foreground, so that

> the ratio of the conductivities of the two phases

is pretty much required, and I'd prefer

> the ratio of the conductivities of two phases

when referring to a more general situation.

Comment: An excellent answer expected only from a mathematics teacher! Yes, you are right Sir. 33 results cannot be considered a statistically significant sample set. In addition, your vote to the first expression, as a native speaker with expertise in mathematics who know the meaning of the term “the ratio of” better than others, worth me more than all 33 objects in my sample set!

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: I think you are right, and what Edwin said.

In formal writing, ratios should be explicitly described as something to something else. So what you should say is something like *the ratio of the conductivity of one phase to that of the other*. For a bigger sample (12,000), I swapped *density* for *conductivity*, and Google Scholar spat out the following for "ratio of the density of" -

> Sgro (1975) has found that there is a characteristic **ratio of the density of the material inside the
>   cloud to that outside the cloud** such that for small density ratios the cloud will be left heated and
>   expanded, but for large density ratios the cloud will be left cooled and compressed
>
> The supernova trigger for formation of the solar system AGW Cameron,
>   JW Truran - Icarus, 1977 - Elsevier -https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0019103577901014

...

> The weakness of the processes H + p - H~ + hv and H + H - Hz + hv
>   indicates the negligible **ratio of the density of Hz to that of H in the intergalactic medium**.
>
> [PDF] Recombination of hydrogen in the hot model of the universe -http://jetp.ac.ru/cgi-bin/dn/e_028_01_0146.pdf

...

> where o is the **ratio of the density of the lead ahead of the shock wave to that behind**.
>
> Further results in the theory of long rod penetration∗ -
>   https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022509669900283

I found no examples in the first few pages of results that were constructed the way your second example is.

Changing the search to *densities*, as in "ratio of the densities of", yields a high proportion of results structured like your first example (out of 3300 hits)-

> For not very high primary energies, one would have to multiply this ratio by a **ratio of the densities
>   of the final electron states** to obtain the actual cross-section ratio
>
> On the long-range correlation model of the photonuclear effect - https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0029558258900051

...

> it is clear that supercritical releases of
>   different densities should give decay constants k, whose ratio is equal to the
>   reciprocal square root of the **ratio of the densities of the fluids**.
>
> The structure and concentration decay of high pressure jets of natural
>   gas - https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00102208408923739

I can't think of any reason why *conductivity* and *density* ought behave differently here. They are both bulk properties of materials. I do think the first example is a bit casual unless you expect the reader to already be familiar with the terms. Note that neither example above is using that construction to introduce new ideas, only to expand on earlier remarks using already familiar terms.

Comment: Gotta love these evidence-based opinions. Especially one so carefully sought out. ;) (As if things out there prove anything. Nevertheless, it is the site "rule")